# trying to add or remove class on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to add the toggleClass but it's not working. i also tried to add or remove the class using the hasClass. there is also same problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".srch-btn").click(function() {
    $(".srch-inpt").toggleClass("expanded");
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.srch-inpt {
  height: 38px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 38px;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.48);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.srch-inpt.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="">
  <button type="button" class="srch-btn">search</button>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" id="s" class="srch-inpt">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: It's not that it is not working, but your `div` in absolute position is blocking the click event on the search button. Remove the absolute and it is working (probably not as expected though).

Comment: The problem is the `.box` div. It's on top of the button and it's making it impossible to click the button.

Comment: A breakpoint in the browser debugger would help you find out whether the event is being fired or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You .box is sitting on top of your button, so the function is never getting called. Even the though your box opacity is 0, it's still 'there', and it's what you're clicking (note the cursor is not a pointer when hovering over the button).

You'll either want to find a different position for your .box, or place it's z-index lower than 0. I've made the latter change in the snippet below.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".srch-btn").click(function() {
    $(".srch-inpt").toggleClass("expanded");
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
}

.srch-inpt {
  height: 38px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 38px;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.48);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.srch-inpt.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="">
  <button type="button" class="srch-btn">search</button>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" id="s" class="srch-inpt">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

To achieve expected reult, use below option of z-index , as input and button are overlapped

```
.srch-btn{
  position:relative;
  z-index:9999
}
```

https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/EQqYJL

Comment: I wouldn't recommend setting z-index to '9999'. Actually, manage the z-index of the different components so that it's easier to maintain in the future.

For example, I had done this a few times in a project in the past and when I came to develop it further a few years in the future - I was setting a z-index of an element to '999' and it wasn't working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
remove position: absolute from .box class.
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".srch-btn").click(function() {
    $(".srch-inpt").toggleClass("expanded");
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  top: 0;
}

.srch-inpt {
  height: 38px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 38px;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.48);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
}

.srch-inpt.expanded {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="">
  <button type="button" class="srch-btn">search</button>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" id="s" class="srch-inpt">
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

It was because your button was underneath the text input field. Giving the button a value of 'relative' to the 'position' property and the setting its 'z-index' slightly higher than the text field will make the button clickable. Adding a transition would make the animation go fluid.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".srch-btn").click(function() {
    $(".srch-inpt").toggleClass("expanded");
    var widthbtn=$(".srch-inpt").width();
    $("button").css({"margin-left":widthbtn+"px","transition":"all 0.1s ease"});
  });
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 300px;
  max-width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.srch-inpt {
  height: 38px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  padding: 10px 38px;
  width: 0;
  background: rgba(166, 166, 166, 0.48);
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #ddd;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.srch-inpt.expanded {
  width: initial;
  opacity: 1;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="searchform" method="get" action="">
  <button type="button" class="srch-btn">search</button>
  <div class="box">
    <input type="text" name="s" value="" id="s" class="srch-inpt">
  </div>
</form>
```